# Stuck with string.translate function in python 3

Tags: python-3.4

```
import os

def rename_files():
    #(1) get file names from a folder
    file_list = os.listdir("my_directory")
    #print(file_list)
    os.chdir("my_directory")
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Current work directory is " + saved_path)
    os.getcwd()
    #(2) for each file, rename filename
    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.chdir("my_directory")

rename_files()
```

And after this I've got an error:

> TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.translate` in python 3.x accepts just one argument i.e. translation table.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

> `str.translate(table)`
>
> Return a copy of the string in which each character has been mapped
>   through the given translation `table`

You can create required translation table using [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans)

```
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('0123456789'))
file_name.translate(table)
```